Python cannot import names from my own files
I have the following code
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_cors import CORS

    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///mydatabase.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Now I try to import it into this file:

    from flask import request, jsonify
    from config import app,db
    from models import Contact



    @app.route("/contacts", methods =["GET"])
    def get_contacts():
        contacts = Contact.query.all()
        json_contacts = list(map(lambda x: x.to_json(), contacts))
        return jsonify({"contacts": json_contacts})

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()

        app.run(debug = True)

And I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Nicov\Uni\FlaskDemo\backend\main.py", line 2, in <module>
from config import app,db
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'config' (c:\Users\Nicov\Uni\FlaskDemo\backend\config.py)

I tried the relative path so
from .config import app,db
it was the same failure I don't know what else to try
projectstructure:

directory backend{main.py, models.py, config.py}


You should include file names and directory structure of where the files reside to make the context clear.

get path from error message c:\Users\Nicov\Uni\FlaskDemo\backend\config.py and open it in editor - maybe you have two files with name config.py and you edit one file (in different folder) but you import other file which doesn't have app.

I could not reproduce the issue. Does import config work?
